# Rails Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

For single table inheritance, how do you force Rails to use an integer column for the 'type' column instead of string?

Comment: It's my experience that when you start putting your fingers so deep into the internals is that you usually eventually wish you didn't

Answer (score 1):

You can override the methods Rails uses to convert the table name to class name and vice versa:

The relevant methods are `find_sti_class` which is responsible for the translating the value stored in the type column to the respective ActiveRecord model and `sti_name` which is responsible for retriving the value stored in type column given an ActiveRecord subclass.

You can override them like this:

```
class Institution::Base < ActiveRecord::Base

  ALLOWED_CLASSES = %w[Institution::NonProfit Institution::Commercial]

  class << self

    def find_sti_class type_name
      idx = type_name.to_i
      super if idx == 0
      ALLOWED_CLASSES[idx-1].constantize
    rescue NameError, TypeError
      super
    end

    def sti_name
      idx = ALLOWED_CLASSES.index(self.name)
      if idx.nil?
        super
      else
        idx + 1
      end
    end

  end

end
```

I have written a [post](http://lorefnon.me/2014/07/27/optimizing-sti-columns.html) elaborating this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find the part of ActiveRecord responsible for handling the "type" column and monkey patch it, i.e. override how it worked from within your application.